# Where can I download english to chinese dictionary database?

Tags: database

Where can I download english to chinese dictionary database?

Comment: if you do not have to do it offline. You may try Google translate API https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/libraries It's paid service AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CEDict is a sizeable Chinese-English dictionary database... depending on what you are doing, it might be enough to use it in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Just google it... , here is one http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cedict

another one : http://hua.umf.maine.edu/China/database.html